# MySql select transactions with their highest status and also ordered by id descendant

Tags: mysql

There is table "T" that stores transaction ids and statuses per transaction:

```
id     txn_id      status
1       001          0
2       001          2
3       002          2
4       002          0
5       002         100
6       003          0
7       003         100
```

I need to get the transactions with their highest status and also ordered by id descendant:

```
id     txn_id      status
7       003         100
5       002         100
2       001          2
```

So far I am using:

```
SELECT id, txn_id, status FROM 1a1_ipn GROUP BY txn_id ORDER BY id DESC
```

But no luck. I am running out of ideas. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result in a single query like this:

```
select t.id , x.txn_id, x.status 
from `1a1_ipn`  t
join (SELECT txn_id, max(status) as status FROM `1a1_ipn`
    GROUP BY txn_id) as x  on t.txn_id = x.txn_id and t.status = x.status
 order by id desc
```

Comment: This works. It's one of the options described in [The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html). See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bd0d9/16).

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical problem encountered when working with databases. There are several techniques to solve it.

Below I've used the `LEFT JOIN` approach, which is considered to be the most efficient:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `1a1_ipn` t1                  
LEFT JOIN `1a1_ipn` t2 ON t1.txn_id = t2.txn_id AND t1.status < t2.status
WHERE t2.status is NULL  
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Live example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bd0d9/2).

The following technique uses an uncorrelated subquery, and is perhaps a bit more intuitive:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM 1a1_ipn ORDER BY status DESC) AS s 
GROUP BY txn_id
ORDER by id DESC
```

Live example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bd0d9/6).

When execution speed is an issue, it is usually better to write a `LEFT JOIN` than a subquery.

For more information on this and other techniques, you can visit [The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).

Comment: You where right, my solution was not correct for this situation. Im remember i used HAVING for similar requirement but it doesn't work here at least. Thank you.

Comment: Wow!!! I like first one! I will remember as a technique to get the max :)
A lot of differences at grouping  between MySQL and T-SQL form Micro$oft